# Attach image using Twitter Share link

Tags: image, twitter

Is it possible to attach an image to a tweet using the Twitter share link?

I'm using the following url to tweet but I can't find away to attach an image. The tweet has a link to the image but I want it attached to the tweet so someone can view the image while reading the tweet.

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=MyTag&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fimage.png
```

Or would have to use the twitter api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/documentation which you can programmer directly with twitter.

```
    // Publish with media
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var tweet = Tweet.CreateTweetWithMedia("I love tweetinvi", file);
var imageURL = tweet.Entities.Medias.First().MediaURL;

// Publish with geo information
var tweet = Tweet.CreateTweet("Hello guys");
tweet.PublishWithGeo(-54.73, -64.2);

// Retweet
tweet.PublishRetweet();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible to upload media through the share link. Probably, a security decision by Twitter.

I suggest you try the [twitpic API](http://dev.twitpic.com).